# How to validate and authenticate a login form on submit button click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am doing a login page validation which requires validation and after that authentication on submit button click. But I am getting validation which I have in my js file but not getting call to the authentication function which is present in the button click of code behind. When I call `btn_Click` function on button's `onserverclick` it is not working.

Suggest me something; How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You use the `OnLoggingIn` of asp.net Login control as:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnLoggingIn="OnLogginIn" > ...
```

and on code behind if you need to cancel the authentication of the user you set `e.Cancel` to `true`

```
protected void OnLogginIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(NotAuthendicateMyRules)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
                    OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn">
```

**Code Behind:**

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string query=String.Format("SELECT * from Users where UserName='{0}' and Password='{1}'",Login1.UserName.ToLower() ,Login1.Password);
        DataSet ds= new DataSet();
        ds= your database access query;
        if(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count>0)
        {
        e.Authenticated = true;
        }   
        else 
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
    }

    protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<i><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm()" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Actually I was using html button so it did not worked but now Iam using asp button using that  it is working.
Here ValidateForm() is a JavaScript function which should validate all your required fields and return true if validated, else false.

Collapse | Copy Code
    
function ValidateForm()
{
    if(allFieldsValidated)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

If it returns true, then button click server event btnSubmit_Click is fired. Else it is not fired.